# Does c-ares support IOS?

Tags: ios, dns, c-ares

Do the c-ares support IOS? 
I need to use c-ares in my company's app running on IOS. But It can't work correctly using "ares_gethostbyname()" and the status code in the callback function returns 11(ARES_ECONNREFUSED) all the time . The same code runs correctly on other opearting system such as Win32, Android.

Glancing over the source code, I found the reason,  that is,  c-ares is  unable to get dns servers on IOS. Because c-ares read the file /etc/resolv.conf to get dns servers information, but this file does not exist on IOS.

So, do the c-ares support IOS? Or What's the method on IOS to get dns servers information?

Answer (score 3):

I found [a patch](http://c-ares.haxx.se/mail/c-ares-archive-2014-12/att-0001/0001-ares_init.c-was-updated-for-IOS-devices.patch) for this that never was merged into the master repo, [posted in December 2014](http://c-ares.haxx.se/mail/c-ares-archive-2014-12/0001.shtml).

It'd be great if you could try it out and report back on the c-ares mailing list so that we can work on getting it merged and supported "officially".

/ awful c-ares maintainer :-(

Comment: Thx!  I also tried to get dns servers information by calling "res_ninit()". But I  find a strange problem. I can get dns server ip correctly when connecting Internet, but it does not work if disconnecting Internet. So I want to know why "res_ninit()" need to connect to the network to get dns servers information?

Comment: If "res_ninit()" need to connect to the network, it will be uncontrollable. Maybe, it will take much time to get dns information. So I think that if Merging this code into "ares_init", it is unacceptable to spend long time to initialize.

Comment: You're mixing subjects. res_init or res_ninit have nothing at all to do with c-ares or how it works.